# Parsing JSON data from CLOB field using PL/SQL

Tags: json, oracle, plsql

I have data in the following format stored in a CLOB field of a table-

```
{
  "key" : "PRODUCT_NAME",
  "value" : "Myproduct"
}, {
  "key" : "PRODUCT_TYPE",
  "value" : "Electronics"
}, {
  "key" : "PRODUCT_PRICE",
  "value" : "123456789.1"
}
```

I want to store them in a table which will be having columns `PRODUCT_NAME`,`PRODUCT_TYPE`,`PRODUCT_PRICE` and they will be stored as

```
PRODUCT_NAME PRODUCT_TYPE PRODUCT_PRICE
MyProduct    Electronics  123456789.1
```

I want to perform these using Pl/SQL.  Any pointers here?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Instead of just asking for a solution to your problem, it pays to post some code that shows what you have tried to do so far. You are then more likely to get help in the form of suggested fixes or alternative approaches.

Comment: Parse the JSON, create commands to insert the data into the table, execute commands. I can't give you anything more specific without more detail in your question.

Comment: Your JSON is invalid, so Oracle functions like `json_table` will refuse to parse it as it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CLOB` field you are using is not a valid JSON, so you can't use the JSON functions directly. You need to go through the [JSON documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/json.htm#ADXDB6246) and understand how a json should be stored in a database table in order to make it easier to use them. One solution for you would be to parse the individual jsons first and then apply `JSON_OBJECT`  on each json. Furthermore, you would need a `PIVOT` or a `MAX(CASE)` block to convert the rows into columns. 
This query  works in Oracle 12c and above.

**Sample data**

```
CREATE TABLE t AS 
  SELECT 1   AS id, 
         To_clob('{   "key" : "PRODUCT_NAME",   "value" : "Myproduct" }, {   "key" : "PRODUCT_TYPE",   "value" : "Electronics" }, {   "key" : "PRODUCT_PRICE",   "value" : "123456789.1" }') AS j 
  FROM   dual 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2, 
         To_clob('{   "key" : "PRODUCT_NAME",   "value" : "Myproduct2" }, {   "key" : "PRODUCT_TYPE",   "value" : "Chemical" }, {   "key" : "PRODUCT_PRICE",   "value" : "25637.1" }') 
  FROM   dual;
```

**Query**

```
WITH jdt AS 
( 
       SELECT id, 
              JSON_VALUE(jsons,'$.key')   AS k,  -- gets the "key"
              JSON_VALUE(jsons,'$.value') AS v   -- gets the "value"
       FROM   ( 
                     SELECT id, 
                            REGEXP_SUBSTR(j,'(.*?)\}(,|$)',1,LEVEL,'n',1) 
                                   || '}' AS jsons --split the clob field into individual jsons
                     FROM   t 
                            CONNECT BY PRIOR id = id 
                     AND    PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL 
                     AND    LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(j,'\}(,|$)') ) ) 
SELECT * 
FROM   jdt pivot ( max ( v ) FOR k IN ( 'PRODUCT_NAME', 
                                       'PRODUCT_TYPE', 
                                       'PRODUCT_PRICE' ) );

 ID PRODUCT_NAME PRODUCT_TYPE   PRODUCT_PRICE
 1  Myproduct    Electronics    123456789.1
 2  Myproduct2   Chemical       25637.1
```

Comment: Thanks Kaushik. It is really helpful. I am just going to try in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use PL/JSON it has various of functions and procedures for JSON parsing https://pljson.github.io/pljson/