# Parsing JSON to relational Table using ORDS

Tags: oracle, web-services, plsql, oracle-ords

I want to parse and insert below JSON to relational table using PL/SQL & ORDS. but I'm stuck at sizes part of below JSON

```
{
  "order_number": "302523001",
  "sizes": {
    "34": 2,
    "33": 4,
    "32": 7,
    "36": 8
  }
}
```

I am using below code to process above

```
INSERT INTO test_sizes_tbl  
      SELECT * FROM json_table  
            (l_po format json, '$' COLUMNS ( 
                order_number varchar2 path '$.order_number', 
                NESTED path '$.sizes[*]' 
                   COLUMNS ( 
                          size_name  varchar2 path '$.key', 
                          size_value varchar2 path '$.value')));
```

Sizes e.g. 32, 33, 34, 36 are dynamic values and there is no way to fix them as key. I need to pick these sizes dynamically and insert into table. How to parse above JSON?

Comment: version of Oracle DB?

Comment: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: try looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51042906/parsing-json-data-from-clob-field-using-pl-sql - your ords solution will mostly likely consist of posting your json doc as a clob, and then writing some PL/SQL to parse it and generate your insert/updates

Comment: I am using raw json with json table to parse but I am not sure that which value to use as a key in json table

Comment: If you were in 12.2, you could use the json data guide function to get a list of attributes, I think

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I am trying to do again using below code but still failed

   INSERT INTO test_sizes_tbl
      SELECT *
        FROM json_table (l_po  format json, '$'
             COLUMNS (
                 order_number          varchar2  path '$.order_number',
                 NESTED                          path '$.sizes[*]'
                   COLUMNS (
                     size_name         varchar2  path '$.key',
                     size_value        varchar2  path '$.value')));

Comment: Add your code to the question